# Highcharts multiple series yAxis autoscaling

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've just encountered a problem with highcharts autoscaling within multiple series. Pictorial explanation:

[Range 12h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwVOt.png)
 -> Here, my time range is 12hours, max value is 5 (yellow).

[Range 16h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHccX.png)
-> Here, when I switch to 16h time period, max value of THE SAME SERIES changes to approx. 2.5 (yellow).

How to retain the same Yaxis max value across all time ranges?
Historical data, form the moment when the chart is initialized back to 16h before, is provided by REST API endpoint, whereas current data is fetched from HTML.

EDIT:

Additionally, when I narrow down the time range, max value apperas to be way bigger, than it is in the normal time range.

[Zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siVMF.png)

Comment: It could be happening because of Highstock `dataGrouping` feature that is enabled by default. Check the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick! However, it has affected the performance of the chart significantly. Is there any way to define 'global' `dataGrouping`, rather than defining it in every series?

Comment: Sure, you can define it in plotOptions for all series. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping. Also, you can change the approximation parameter to control the grouping as you like: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation